# sql create database from variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have `@db_out = 'aux.dbo.some_table_name'` , and I don't know how to drop , create based on that variable like :

```
IF OBJECT_ID(@db_out) IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE "@db_out" - not working
CREATE TABLE "@db_out"  .... etc
```

it creates master.dbo.@dbo_out

How can I use that variable to create that table or verify it and drop it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to build the statement in varchar variable and execute it:

```
declare @strSql as varchar(max)

IF OBJECT_ID(@db_out) IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
   EXEC ('DROP TABLE [' + @db_out + ']')
END
set @strSql = 'CREATE TABLE [' + @db_out + '] (' -- Etc
EXEC (@strSql)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to write dynamic SQL.

```
SET @sql = 'IF OBJECT_ID(@db_out) IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE ' + @db_out + '; '
SET @sql = @sql + 'CREATE TABLE ' + @db_out + ' (...)'
EXEC(@sql)
```